# Angular 10 and Webpack 4 Duplicate Split Chunks With Max Size Set

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4

Have a very large Angular 10 project and when using splitChunks, I am getting over 90 chunks which several of them are 3+ MB a piece.

One of my entry points is "./angular/main.ts" which bootstraps the entire app and this one is also over 3MB a piece.

The biggest problem I have is when I try to update this app and push the new bundled files onto S3, when the new service worker installs and it goes to fetch the new files, it is downloading several of these 3+ MB files and on a cell phone with bad internet, it is extremely slow!

So what I have tried to do is use the maxSize option on splitChunks and I end up getting duplicated chunk files.  For example chunk 250 looks like this:

[250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257]
Code...

and then the next chunk is 251 and that looks like this:

[251, 250, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257]
Code...

But the actual code is the exact same.  So now when I make a change its going and downloading a ton of duplicated files and its way worse now than before.

I have probably 50 modules in the angular app, how can I make this automatically split and reuse things so that if I go and change 1 module's page and I update, that the only chunk I have to download is that 1 small chunk for that module.

```
splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      minSize: 0,
      //minSize: 1, 
      //maxSize: 100000, CAUSING THE DUPLICATES
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            if (module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)) {
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            }
          },
          chunks: 'all',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        },
        appversion: {
          test: /app\.service\.ts/,
          name(module) {},
          chunks: 'all',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
```